# Sound clipping/clicking when lowering volume with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

Audio is clipping (or clicking) when trying to lower the volume of a WAV file in real time.

I've tried it on a `SampleChannel`, `VolumeSampleProvider` and `WaveChannel32` instance, the source being a *32bit WAV file*.

If I try it on a `WaveOut` instance, the clipping doesn't occur anymore, but I don't want that because it lowers the volume of all sounds in the application.

And this only happens when I lower volume, rising it doesn't cause clipping.

Is this a known problem or am I supposed to approach this differently?

**Note:** *this is how the volume drops in real time over the given time span:*

```
0.9523049
0.9246111
0.9199954
0.89384
0.8676848
0.8415294
0.8169126
0.7907572
0.7646018
0.739985
0.7122912
0.6892129
0.6630576
0.6369023
0.6122856
0.5861301
0.5599748
0.535358
0.5092026
0.4830474
0.456892
0.4322752
0.4061199
0.3799645
0.3553477
0.3276539
0.3030371
0.2784202
0.2522649
0.2261095
0.2014928
0.176876
0.149182
0.1245652
0.09841
0.07225461
0.04763785
0.02148246
0
```

Comment: Are you sure the volume is 1.0 before you start to apply these factors? Are you sure no other values get set during this actions?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the volume always starts at 1.0 and no other values get set during the actions. I made sure by isolating the case so no other factors can interfere.

Comment: Ok, apparently it is a `DesiredLatency` and `NumberOfBuffers` issue on the `WaveOut` instance. The default values cause the problem, altered values fix it.

Comment: You could answer your own questions to allow others to find this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a `DesiredLatency` and `NumberOfBuffers` issue on the `WaveOut` instance. The default values cause the problem, altered values fix it.

These are the values I used to fix the issue.

```
 WaveOutDevice = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.NewWindow())
        {
            DesiredLatency = 700, //! adjust the value to prevent sound clipping/clicking
            NumberOfBuffers = 3, //! number of buffers must be carefully selected to prevent audio clipping/clicking
        };
```

Comment: if you need to up these values it means that your PC is struggling to keep up filling the buffers? Is this a low spec computer? Or are you doing some intensive DSP/graphics?

Comment: Hello, Mark. My system is Windows 7 Ultimate x64, with 16GB of RAM and a core i5-2500K 3.3Ghz quad-core. I think the issue is related to different output devices rather than the system itself.

Also, the optimum values in my case is 3 buffers; if I use less than 3 or more than 3, I still have problems.

Comment: Have you tried with WaveOutEvent, or maybe with WasapiOut or DirectSoundOut to see if that makes a difference. Last time I needed to use settings like that was on my 400MHz Pentium II ;)

Comment: No, I haven't because I wasn't aware of those. Your library is pretty complex and I haven't found any solid documentation to it, mostly examples scattered all over the Internet. Either way, it's an amazing tool and pretty much the only one around which programmers can rely on, so thank you very much for making it available and constantly improving it. Yesterday I used your sound loop example and added my own improvements to create truly flawless audio loops; would've it not been for your library, I find it hard to imagine a different way to perfectly loop audio in a C# project.

Comment: I had the issue of sound clipping whem just playing the audiofile, using the NAudioEngine class of Jacob Johnston.  DesiredLatency on WaveOut was set to 100, Buffers default. DesiredLatency = 300 and NumberOfBuffers = 3 worked for me. Thanks for sharing, helped me a lot!